# undefined value of i when used with sequence point in printf

Tags: c, mingw

I was looking at sequence point operations. In the code below, the value of i is printed as 1. But I get the warning message that "Operation on i is undefined".  I was thinking that though & operator is not a sequence point, but function call printf is considered as a sequence point and hence i is completely evaluated during %d. But Why the operation is undefined?

```
int i = 0;
if((i++) & printf("i = %d\n",i))
{
    // Something
}
else
{
    // some code here
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use the *logical* and operator `&&` instead of the bitwise? Logical and with `&&` is a sequence point. Though that would inhibit the call to `printf` since the result of `i++` in this case is zero which is false.

Comment: My intention here was specifically to test i value without && (or ||). So I meant & operator and not && as I specified in my OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function call is a sequence point, but arguments to the function are evaluated before the function call. So `i++` and `i` as an argument to printf are unsequenced.

Comment: If arguments are evaluated before the call, printf should consider the value of 0 for i (before incrementing) right?

Comment: @Rajesh No, because arguments are only evaluated before the call. It's undefined if they should be evaluated before or after `i++`. That's what sequence points are about.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
if((i++) & printf("i = %d\n",i))
```

This is bit wise anding two expressions, one of which is the returned value from`printf()`

Suggest using:

```
if((i++) && printf("i = %d\n",i))
```

which is a logical 'and'

Also, there is still some doubt about what the value of 'i' will be when printed.  Suggest:

```
if( i && printf("i = %d\n",i))
i++;
```

Which will implement the logic as your question and following comments indicate to be the desired logic.

Note: it is (usually) a bad idea to use 'side effects' in your code.